# ML.NET Integration in Blazor - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ML.Vision' The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, blazor, ml.net

I am trying to implement ML.NET model into a Blazor server app and it throws this error.
[image: Code]

```
public static class AIModel
{
    public enum Label
    {
        Undefined,
        Bolnav,
        Sanatos
    }
    private static string MLNetModelPath = "BlazorTWProject.AiModelMers.zip";

    public static readonly Lazy<PredictionEngine<ImageInput, ImageOutput>> PredictEngine = new Lazy<PredictionEngine<ImageInput, ImageOutput>>(AIModel.CreatePredictEngine, true);

    public static ImageOutput Predict(ImageInput input)
    {
        var predEngine = PredictEngine.Value;
        return predEngine.Predict(input);
    }

    private static PredictionEngine<ImageInput, ImageOutput> CreatePredictEngine()
    {
        MLContext? mlContext = new MLContext();

        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var files= thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        using var stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(MLNetModelPath) ;
        ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(stream, out DataViewSchema _);
        return mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ImageInput, ImageOutput>(mlModel);
    }
}
```

I tried to add the zip file to the embedded resources but nothing worked.
I want to specify that even it does say that it can't find the file, if I change the stream parameter to a non-existing file path, the code throws an System.IO.File error, not System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I haven't installed all the NuGet Packages required for the model.
After I installed all `ML.Vision, ML.ImageAnalytics, ...` the problem was solved.

Comment: Since answer for your particular problem seems quite trivial, maybe it's best to remove your question.

Comment: Well, I thought I might leave it here because there was nowhere to find that problem and I think it's a common one for ML.NET.